# Trouble with column output

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

1. Trouble with IPAddress column. Output with PowerShell to the excel csv.
   shows Error System String []. All other columns show as need. Actual ip in the column wont output on the excel csv output.
2. List item I'm trying to correct on excel csv.
   IPAddress column,

Etc

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\EXAMPLE\Computers.txt"

$osColumns = 'PSComputerName', 'Caption', 'OSArchitecture', 'Version', 'BuildNumber'
$biosColumns = 'PSComputerName', 'Manufacturer', 'SerialNumber', 'SMBIOSBIOSVersion'
$lastbootColumns = 'csname', 'lastbootuptime'
$IPColumns = 'DNSHostName', 'IPAddress', 'MACAddress'


$OSinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object $osColumns
$BIOSinfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object $biosColumns
$lastboot = Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object $lastbootColumns
$IPinfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computers | Select-Object $IPColumns


$computerInfo = foreach( $computer in $computers ) {
  $thisOSInfo = $OSInfo | Where-Object { $_.PSComputerName -eq $computer }
  $thisBIOSInfo = $BIOSinfo | Where-Object { $_.PSComputerName -eq $computer }
  $thisLastboot = $lastboot | Where-Object { $_.csname -eq $computer }
  $thisIPInfo = $IPinfo | Where-Object { $_.DNSHostName -eq $computer }

  
  $row = @{}
  foreach( $prop in @( $thisOSInfo.psobject.Properties.Name ) ) {
    if( $prop -in $osColumns ) {
      $row[$prop] = $thisOSInfo.$prop
    }
  }

  foreach( $prop in @( $thisBIOSInfo.psobject.Properties.Name ) ) {
    if( $prop -in $biosColumns ) {
      $row[$prop] = $thisBIOSInfo.$prop
    }
  }

  foreach( $prop in @( $thisLastboot.psobject.Properties.Name ) ) {
    if( $prop -in $lastbootColumns ) {
      $row[$prop] = $thisLastboot.$prop
    }
  }
  
  foreach( $prop in @( $thisIPInfo.psobject.Properties.Name ) ) {
    if( $prop -in $IPColumns ) {
      $row[$prop] = $thisIPInfo.$prop
    }

  }
  [PSCustomObject]$row
}

$computerInfo | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\EXAMPLE\report.csv
```

Comment: Your description of the issue isn’t very clear - can you give an example input file, the current output and the desired output.

Comment: `$thisIPInfo` will be an array of objects how are you planning to merge it?

Comment: in excel .csv the column example: Under  macaddress column it shows xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx. and under the ipaddress column it should show xx.xx.xx.xx but it just shows the error system string[] inplace of the IP.

Comment: ```System.String[]``` is not an error - it’s how Powershell serialises an array of strings. This indicates the value for the IP address is *not* a single value but an array - maybe with a single value in it, but an array nonetheless. You’ll need to either turn this into a string yourself, or turn it into a different value so PowerShell’s default serialisation gives you the string you want.

Comment: I used | out-gridview and this shows IP in IPaddress column.